# A question about HTT Lemma 5.5.2.1

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, higher-category-theory

I have a question about the statement of Lemma 5.5.2.1 in Lurie's [`Higher Topos Theory'](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HTT.pdf).

``Let $S$ be a small simplicial set, let $f: S\rightarrow \mathcal{S}$ be an object of $\mathcal{P}(S^{op})$, and let $F: \mathcal{P}(S^{op})\rightarrow \widehat{\mathcal{S}}$ be the functor corepresented by $f$. Then the composition 
$$S\overset{j}{\rightarrow}\mathcal{P}(S^{op})\overset{F}{\rightarrow}\widehat{\mathcal{S}}$$
is equivalent to $f$.
"

The Yoneda embedding $j$ should be from $S$ to $\mathcal{P}(S)$, but the last line doesn't seem to be just a typo. Do I miss something? Thanks!

Comment: The usual Yoneda embedding is from $S^{\operatorname{op}}$ to $\mathcal{P}(S)$ - to get $j$, apply the Yoneda embedding to $S^{\operatorname{op}}.$

Comment: Thanks for fixing HTT. That is my reason for the vote up.

Comment: By the way, we field short questions like this in the homotopy theory chat here.

Comment: The second and third P(S^op)’s should have an extra op on the outside, yeah? That ought to do it.

Comment: @dhy No, this is actually a typo.  The usual Yoneda embedding goes from $S\hookrightarrow \mathcal{P}(S)$.  Presheaves are contravariant. Dylan's comment makes this correct.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz Thanks for the suggestion of fixing it.

Comment: @HarryGindi Next time I'll ask such questions in the chat.

Comment: @DylanWilson Yes, that works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The middle term should be $\mathcal{P}(S^{op})^{op}$. The Yoneda embedding gives a functor $S^{op} \to \mathcal{P}(S^{op})$. The functor corepresented by $f \in \mathcal{P}(S^{op})$ is given by $Hom_{\mathcal{P}(S^{op})}(-,f)$, which is a functor $\mathcal{P}(S^{op})^{op} \to \widehat{\mathcal{S}}$.

As a reality check, the analogous theorem in ordinary category is that the composite
$$
x \mapsto Hom_S(x,-) \mapsto Nat(Hom_S(x,-),f)
$$
is naturally isomorphic via the Yoneda lemma to the functor $x \mapsto f(x)$.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer! I was confused about corepresented v.s represented.